# rasterize gradient from shapely object with rasterio

Tags: python, shapely, rasterio

I have an array of horizontal and non-horizontal 3d-polygons as shapely objects, and I want to rasterize them into a depth map

For horizontal ones, it's just drawing their height as color, but I also need to render a gradient for the non-horizontal ones; how should I approach that?